# Continuous updating strip chart ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to implement a strip chart that will be continuously updating via data from a sensor. I've been googlling around and  I can seem to find out how to implement this. There will be a continuous data feed from a censor so I want to try and make a dynamic strip chart where it will continuously update with the data from the sensor. Is this even possible?

I'm trying to do all of this in ASP.NET , C#

Answer (score 0):

How often are the updates? There are a variety of different approaches, the most reliable method would be a polling AJAX update to re-download the image (assuming the chart is an image). An alternative is [a Comet update](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).

Comment: it's continuous, the data is a feed from a bunch of sensors so it's consistently updating. I've been trying to get it to work with asp:ChartControl but i can only get the chart to render once it's read a fixed number of data from a file. I've been trying to render it, then continuously adding points so I can see the graph dynamically updated with every new data point. I read somewhere that you can use some chart feature which doesn't plot eveyr single point but draws a shape clsoe enough to what the data resembles to save the processing power? do you happen to know anything of this?